# Priorities to queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway I can give priorities to thread for different queries in SQL.
I have multiple queries running on a table at same time(Some are important while some are not that important). Is there anyway that i can give priorities to these queries

Suppose there are 10 users running queries parallely on the same database. It there anyway that 1 single user can get more priority(more threads) to his queries.

Comment: You must have something that executes those queries? This is where you should be prioritising.

Answer (score 2):

## SQL Server

Use Resource Governor in sql 2008:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx

## MySql

*As requested before your edit,* here's how to set priorities in MySQL. Use [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) for inserts; [`LOW PRIORITY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) for updates; and for selects  there is [`HIGH PRIORITY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)